# How to use crypt_gensalt() in crypt.h

Tags: c, crypt

According to crypt.h:

```c
extern char *crypt_gensalt (const char *__prefix, unsigned long __count,
                            const char *__rbytes, int __nrbytes)
```

I understand that `__prefix` is encryption type (i.e. $2a$, $5$, $6$,...). My guess is `__rbyte` is the passphrase and `__nrbytes` is the size of passphrase.
How about `__count`? What should I pass into it? I'm going to use `$6$` prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page: https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/libcrypt1-dev/crypt_gensalt_rn.3.en.html

> `count` controls the CPU time cost of the hash; the valid range for count and the exact meaning of “CPU time cost” depends on the hashing method, but larger numbers correspond to more costly hashes.

See also https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/libcrypt1-dev/crypt.5.en.html

For `$6$` (which is `sha512crypt`)

> CPU time cost parameter
> 1000 to 999,999,999

and

> The default CPU time cost parameter is 5000, which is too low for modern hardware.